# Correct me in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have rating system css, html and jquery code. Hover over the star(color) is fine but when i click the star and remove the cursor then it's same. I want to hover over the star and clicked and then color should be changed. sorry for my english but i think you got it. here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rating').click(function() {
    $('.rating span').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
  });
});
```

```css
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}

.rating>span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 14px;
  color: #c4b8b8;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.rating>span:hover,
.rating>span:hover~span {
  color: transparent;
}

.rating>span:hover:before,
.rating>span:hover~span:before {
  content: "\2605";
  position: absolute;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rating">
  <span class="star1">★</span>
  <span class="star2">★</span>
  <span class="star3">★</span>
  <span class="star4">★</span>
  <span class="star5">★</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Here you have a demo almost the same, hope it helps you: https://codepen.io/depy/pen/vEWWdw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, two problenms:

1) You're applying the `checked` class to the *parent* of the div being clicked (`<body>`) not the *individual star.* I had to adjust the jQuery click code to target each star rather than the div.

2) You have no CSS to target the `checked` class.  I added that to the same CSS code that deals with the on-hover.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rating span').click(function() {
    $('.checked').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).addClass('checked');
  });
});
```

```css
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}

.rating>span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 14px;
  color: #c4b8b8;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.rating>span:hover,
.rating>span:hover~span {
  color: transparent;
}

.rating>span:hover:before,
.rating>span:hover~span:before,
.checked:before,
.checked~span:before {
  content: "\2605";
  position: absolute;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rating">
  <span class="star1">★</span>
  <span class="star2">★</span>
  <span class="star3">★</span>
  <span class="star4">★</span>
  <span class="star5">★</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your click function was not tracking the star user clicked on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rating span').click(function() {
    $('.rating span').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).addClass('checked');
  });
});
```

```css
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}

.rating>span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 14px;
  color: #c4b8b8;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.rating>span:hover,
.rating>span:hover~span {
  color: transparent;
}

.rating>span:hover:before,
.rating>span:hover~span:before,
.rating>span.checked:before,
.rating>span.checked~span:before {
  content: "\2605";
  position: absolute;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rating">
  <span class="star1">★</span>
  <span class="star2">★</span>
  <span class="star3">★</span>
  <span class="star4">★</span>
  <span class="star5">★</span>
</div>
```